# Flash Remoting and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, remoting

I'm having some issues trying to get Flash remoting to work with a Rails project. Specifically, I'm a little confused about the configuration.

I'm using WebOrb for Rails to interface Flash and Rails. What I want to do is to be able to run a local Flash Builder project locally, and have it remote to another server running the Rails application and database on another machine.

To be honest, I don't really know where to start, specifically with actually getting it configured to talk to the other machine. The server running Rails is running Ubuntu, and I'm planning on using Flash on both my Mac and Windows machines.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.